# PHP trim() not trimming space

Tags: php, trim

I have run into a strange problem. I am trying to trim a string using php `trim()`, but it is not working.

Here is my code

```
echo $deal->{self::DEAL_BUSINESS};
echo '<br>';
echo trim($deal->{self::DEAL_BUSINESS});
echo '<br>';
```

And here is the output

```
 Alkaram Studio
 Alkaram Studio
```

If it is not clear from the output. There is a space in the beginning of both untrimmed and the trimmed string.

In the view source I got this.

```
&nbsp;Alkaram Studio
```

Comment: you can solve issue using  Regular Expression .

Comment: ok. could you please give me a link? and why is trim not working?

Comment: the `DEAL_BUSINESS` property, how do you set the value?

Comment: i was wrong and have deleted my post- good luck in finding the correct answer

Comment: it comes from an excel file that I upload.

Comment: If `DEAL_BUSINESS` contains a leading non-breaking space, `trim()` won't remove it.

Comment: I saw in the docs about a second argument to trim() what would be character for that?

Comment: `trim` should work. Would you mind posting the output of `var_dump(trim($deal->{self::DEAL_BUSINESS}));' ?

Comment: do a view-source, and paste the output here, exactly how it shows in the document source

Comment: if trim() not removing you character from the beginning, then that might be a character other than these \t\n\r\0\x0B , try to figure out that character and use that in 2nd parameter of trim().   FYI, http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: its a non-breaking space. You were right @AlexAndrei... how do i fix it.?

Comment: Use that in 2nd parameter of trim() as i mention earlier comment. or you can use str_replace as well

Comment: update the question to show what you got

Comment: yes.. what is that character.. in the second param we need to pass in characters like backslash and a value.. i dont know that for nbsp;

Comment: Regular Expression can solve your issue learn about http://php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php

Comment: Non-breaking spaces can be troublesome with trim: see the first "User Contributed Notes" of  http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php  hope helps. on that page search with "Non-breaking spaces"

Comment: @Mubashar Abbas va aleykoum salam

Comment: @HddnTHA wa rahmatullah wa barakatuho brother.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo trim($deal->{self::DEAL_BUSINESS}, "\xC2\xA0\n");
```

Or

```
$text = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~siu','',$deal->{self::DEAL_BUSINESS});
echo $text;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man.. the second one worked. could you please tell my how `preg_replace` works..

Comment: Simply because a non breaking space is U+00A0 (Unicode). You can read about the regex modifiers in here : http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php